# Proof using matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $C$ and $D$ be non-singular square matrices such that $$(c+d)^{-1} = c^{-1} + d^{-1} $$
Let $T=CD^{-1}$. Prove that $T + T^{-1} = -I $

Comment: what are $c$ and $d$? This statement is not true in general

Comment: square non singular matrices, sorry

Comment: $T+T^{-1} = I \Rightarrow T^2 - T + I = 0$. That is, the minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide $x^2 - x + 1$ and hence $T$ can have eigenvalues $\in \{ \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$. And in all other cases, your statement doesn't hold. It's not true in general.

Comment: Also $(c+d)^{-1} = c^{-1} + d^{-1}$ is hardly ever true.

Comment: I've rewritten the problem to match what the OP has indicated in the comments and deleted my answer (which answered the question the OP wrote but not the question the OP meant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Supposedly using 
>   $$(c+d)^{-1} = c^{-1} + d^{-1} $$

If you assume the above (which is not true in general, for arbitrary matrices $c,d\,$) then:

$$
I = (c+d)(c+d)^{-1}=(c+d)(c^{-1}+d^{-1})= I + cd^{-1} + dc^{-1} + I= 2\,I + t + t^{-1}
$$

The latter gives $t+t^{-1} = -I\,$ as asked.

Comment: whoops meant to be -I thanks

Comment: @Aristotle The question would be a lot more clear if you replaced `Supposedly using` with `Given that`.